# How can I make perfect sticky rice?

Tags: rice, asian-cuisine, chinese-cuisine

I have a couple of weeks off of school, and thought I would try my hand at some dim sum, specifically lotus leaf wraps, but first I need to figure out how to make the sticky rice.  So:

- What type of rice would be best for this purpose?
- What is the optimal way to prepare it (i.e. to be as sticky as possible while still being firm)?
- Anything else I should know before trying it out?

Comment: Yes... But you may want to reword ypour question. Recipe requests are off topic. If you post a recipe or something you're thinking of trying, we can help explain or maybe help you improve it.

Comment: I've made a lot of assumptions in editing your question; however, as it was originally worded I would have had to close it.  If my assumptions are wrong then please feel free to make the appropriate corrections - just please make sure that it's not worded as a recipe request, as those are off-topic here.  Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, first question I've ever posted.  I would say your assumptions are spot on, I am really looking for some pointers in making  a nice sticky rice, not a recipe.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am happy to give you a brief idea, but you may have to tell me how much info you need

1. Get the lotus leaves from chinese shop and they are usually dried leaves, so you need to soak them in water for a night.  After that give it a wash and cut it to the right side
2. sticky rice is a type of rice, so that's what you need. Don't use any other rice as they won't stick. You will need to soak the rice in water for couple of hours and add couple drops of oil.
3. Prepare whatever you want to put in your rice like mushroom and meat
4. When u make the wrap, put a layer of rice on the leaf and then place the meat and mushroom on the rice.  After that put another layer of rice on top and wrap it up
5. Put the wrapped rice to steam and I cannot help you with the time, but it's between 10-20 mins

Good luck

Comment: Note that "sticky rice" is often sold in Asian markets as *glutinous rice*.